# how to close help in vim

Tags: vim

I wrote `:help x11-selection` on vim. Help appear for that command . Now my Vim screen split to two part first is the vim help below that there is my previous text file. Now I want to come back to my text file or better to say I want to hide help window so How?

Comment: Have you tried typing `:quit` for the help window?

Comment: "Now" I do and work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use either `:q` or `:quit` to quit the help window.

[Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/help.html) for your reference.